# two columns overlap before changing to a single column in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two column bootstrap page as shown below. The left contains two rows (an image and a bordered bit of text below the image that fills the whole column width), the right is login details.

The image is 700px wide, and for smaller devices or screen widths I change to a smaller image. This all works fine. However when I resize the browser the right login column overlaps the left column's 700px image by about 40 pixels before it snaps to a single column.

I tried to fix this by putting in a minimum width for the left hand column like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="min-width: 768px">
```

Which worked and it snapped correctly, however on doing so the left hand side main bordered text (that is a row below this image) then became fixed width and did not resize.

How can I get it so the two columns do not overlap and the text still flows in my bordered text.

thanks.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <DIV class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img class="loginPic hidden-xs"  src="images/pic.png" >
                        <img class="loginPic visible-xs"  src="images/pic-small.png" >
                    </DIV>
                </div>
                <br />
                <DIV class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #00549d; border-radius:10px;">
                            <div style="padding:20px;font-size: 13px;">
                                <p>Lots of text.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </DIV>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 pull-left" >login stuff here</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, introducing your own modifications to how columns are laid out (min-width) is definitively not the way to go, that will lead to unwanted/unexpected side effects in one place or another. What actually makes the columns overlap here is hard to tell with code only (creating a [mcve] might help), but it might be due to your image simply being wider than the column definition allows. Maybe add the `img-responsive` class, so that it doesn’t get wider than the column. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: That is superb! I have much to learn about bootstrap classes. I can now get rid of my smaller image. I'll write your solution as an answer?

Comment: Sure, if you want to make that into an answer yourself, go ahead :)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you I had a similar issue, using a smaller content (reducing image size/text font-size) allowed to correctly fit and no overlap happens anymore.